# How do I apply shrinkwrap to my objects and remove it again?

Tags: python, modifiers, shrinkwrap

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SHRINKWRAP')
bpy.data.objects["Icosphere"].modifiers["Shrinkwrap"].target = bpy.data.objects["Specimen"]
```

I have been using the above code to apply a shrinkwrap modifier to the icosphere in my scene, targeting the Specimen mesh. However, I don't know the code to apply the shrinkwrap, and set it in stone so I can collect data from the icosphere. Furthermore, I would like to remove the shrinkwrapping afterwards, so the Icosphere returns to its original shape.

Any help with either of these problems then please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Hello ! You should try to ask only 1 question per post to make sure you get focused answers. But FYI you can't unapply a modifier in the way you're thinking because Blender doesn't keep these operations in memory (apart from using the undo system but I wouldn't rely on that, especially when modifying mesh data)

Comment: If you can afford the memory, you could automatically do what many people do manually:  create a copy of the mesh and stash it away in a collection that isn't included in the scene or render.  Then to 'undo' the application of the modifier, you keep a list of what mesh you stashed away and replace the modified mesh with that one.  It's a bit tricky because of things like UV Maps, but it's possible